# How to Change Multiple lines of Numbers with URL in PHP

Tags: php, url

I have a list of Numbers I want to change it in URL.

```
<?php 
$data "3337315417
3353100401
3337353827
 3362572506";
?>
```

I want to change all of above listed numbers with URLs like below.

```
<a href="https://wa.me/3337315417" >3337315417</a>
<a href="https://wa.me/3353100401" >3353100401</a>
<a href="https://wa.me/3337353827" >3337353827</a>
<a href="https://wa.me/3362572506" >3362572506</a>
```

Please tell me how to do this in PHP

Comment: You can use `explode(" ", $data)` to turn your string into an array and loop through it.

Comment: Dear @catcon Provide me php working source code.

Comment: @NaeemHussain Please note the this isn't a code writing service - don't ask people to write the code for you. **Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. We are here to help but you are meant to do your research and make at least some attempt at doing it yourself before posting, and your question should include details of what you tried and what isn't working.

Comment: Dear @FluffyKitten Basically sir I am developing 100 tools. Where i find out some problems that is why. I got it. I will never ask for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data appears to be separated by vertical as well as horizontal whitespace, it's easier to split it using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) than [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). In this case we use a regex of `\s+` which will split the string on any sequence of one or more whitespace characters (space, tab, return, newline etc). Once it is split, it is an easy task to loop over the data and output the desired string:

```
foreach (preg_split('/\s+/', $data) as $num) {
    echo "<a href=\"https://wa.me/$num\" >$num</a>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<a href="https://wa.me/3337315417" >3337315417</a> 
<a href="https://wa.me/3353100401" >3353100401</a> 
<a href="https://wa.me/3337353827" >3337353827</a> 
<a href="https://wa.me/3362572506" >3362572506</a>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Tl3Lp)

Comment: Dear @Nick I got error in code.syntax error, unexpected ''3337315417 ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: @NaeemHussain I've added a demo link to the answer. Note your code is missing a `=` between `$data` and `"3337315417`